# What is the formula for +/- variances

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create a column in a table that calculates a date of 30 days + or - 14 days. How do I create a formula with an allowed window of deviation?

So far all my equations are on dates without windows for example "=A1 +7".

Comment: Can you explain your question a little further? You want to calculate a Date?

Comment: Give us a screenshot of what you would expect your output to be - showing column headers etc

Comment: Are you trying to create an array formula that spits out two results, one plus 14 days, the other minus 14 days? Or do you need to type the +- symbol in the heading of the column, which is a very different thing? Have you tried insert -> symbol? You'll find ± there.